# How to use custom annotations in a Grails Domain Class?

Tags: grails, aspectj

My custom annotation works fine on a **service** method but is ignored when put on a **domain's** method. Do I have to add domain folder scan for weaving or something? What am I missing?

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface PrintHello {
}
```

And the aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
class PrintHelloAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(PrintHello)")
    public Object printHello(ProceedingJointPoint jp) {
      println "hello"
      return jp.proceed()
    }
}
```

Grails version: 2.4.4.

Comment: Might be of use: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/creating-custom-annotations-for-domain-classes-td4487250.html,

Comment: This has nothing to do with DDD.

Comment: You're right, I'll remove the label. I was thinking if this is something DDD experts might have already faced.